# Handling Native Objects in REST API

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-ffi

I have a web server api implemented using expressjs which provides at REST api for recording web cameras connected to the web server machine.

The web cameras and encoding are handled using a dll written in C++ and interop is done using the [node-ffi](https://github.com/rbranson/node-ffi) library.

The problem I'm having is that I am mixing native ffi handles with JSON stringification in my responses.

e.g. I have a `Stream` class with the prototype:

```
Stream.prototype.id = '';
Stream.prototype.url = '':
Stream.prototype.parent = null;
Stream.prototype.filePtr = null;
```

Where `Stream.filePtr` will contain a ffi handle e.g. `ref.refType(ref.types.void)`

Then in my expressjs POST `start` call I do something like:

```
impl.start = function(req, res){
    var camera = cameras.find(function(camera) {
        return camera.id === req.params.camera;
    });

    res.send(camera.startStream()); // startStream returns a new 'Stream' object.
};
```

As you can see I simply send the `Stream` object as is to the response. Which is how I usually implement REST APIs. The problem is that the native `filePtr` handle shouldn't really be included and I'm unsure what the best practice for this is or if I'm doing something fundamentally wrong?

*NOTE: I'm a novice when it comes to web, nodejs, expressjs and javascript in general. So if something I am doing doesn't make sense or could be done better please point it out.*

A more complete example:

```
// dll bindings

var fileType = ref.types.void;
var filePtrType = ref.refType(fileType);
var cameraType = ref.types.void;
var cameraPtrType = ref.refType(cameraType);

var myLib = ffi.Library(/* Stuff */):

// expressjs api definitions

app.post('api/cameras/:camera/streams', impl.start);
app.delete('api/cameras/:camera/streams/:stream', impl.stop);
app.get('api/cameras', impl.cameras);
app.get('api/cameras/:camera', impl.camera);
app.get('api/cameras/:camera/streams', impl.streams);
app.get('api/cameras/:camera/streams/:stream', impl.stream);

// objects definitions

function Stream() {
    this.id = Date.now();
    this.url = this.id + '.mp4';
};

Stream.prototype.id = '';
Stream.prototype.url = '':
Stream.prototype.parent = null;
Stream.prototype.filePtr = null;

function Camera(id, device){
    this.id = id;
    this.device = device;
    this.cameraPtr = myLib.openCamera(device);  
};

Camera.prototype.id = '';
Camera.prototype.device = 0;
Camera.prototype.cameraPtr = null;

Camera.prototype.startStream = function() {
    var stream = new Stream(this);
    stream.filePtr = myLib.openFile(this.cameraPtr, stream.url);
    return stream;
};

Camera.prototype.stopStream = function(stream) {
    myLib.closeFile(stream.filePtr);
    this.streams.slice(this.streams.indexOf(stream), 1);
};

// object declaration

var cameras = [];

var numCameras = myLib.num_cameras();

for (var n = 0; n < numCameras; ++n) {
    cameras.push(new Camera(n, n));
}

// express api implementation

var impl = {};

impl.streams = function(req, res) {
    var camera = cameras.find(function(camera) {
        return camera.id === req.params.camera;
    });
    res.send(camera.streams);
};

impl.start = function(req, res){
    var camera = cameras.find(function(camera) {
        return camera.id === req.params.camera;
    });

    res.send(camera.startStream());
};

impl.stop = function(req. res) {
    var camera = cameras.find(function(camera){
        return camera.id === req.params.camera;
    });
    var stream = camera.streams.find(function(stream) {
        return stream.id === req.params.stream:
    });
    camera.stopStream(stream);
};

/* Stuff */
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to pipe the stream data to the response rather than returning the stream directly.  Try this.  Here are the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) about pipe.

```
var readableStream = camera.startStream();
readableStream.pipe(res);
```

***Edit***

Well, actually, you probably don't want to end the writableStream (response is a writableStream) as soon as you run out of data (since you're streaming), so try this if the above doesn't work:

```
   var readableStream = camera.startStream();
   readableStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
     res.write(chunk);
   })
```

***Other thoughts***

If you want to return multiple streams at once you may need to make separate http requests for each.  Returning multiple streams at once (unless you did something extremely clever) would likely just send back a jumble of mixed up data.

***To try and answer the actual question***

When the client requests a stream, obviously you can't return raw data as JSON since JSON doesn't allow that.  I would recommend when the client requests a stream resource to return a resource location (a URL) that the client should request.  I believe that is the proper REST way, but I'm not an expert on it.  This is how the interaction would go:

Client: (via GET) Please give me the stream

Server: response (json) here's where you need to go to get that (plus metadata [optional])

Client: Please give me jsonResponse.streamURL

Server: (streams to response)....

Comment: Good idea, I'll try that. However, it does not answer my question :).

Comment: I am already creating the http streams inside of the dll. What I'm having problems with is building the REST api for controlling the streams.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I misinterpreted what you were asking; I assumed that writing the data to the response would handle your issue since the `filePtr` wouldn't be exposed.  Brain isn't quite working yet this morning.